# Why does count() return 0 here?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have the following code :

```
echo $gibs=Db::getResult($sql,$query);
  print_r($gibs);
  count($gibs);
  if($gibid!='' && count($gibs)<=0){
   $gibs=array(
    'gibid'=>$gibid,
    'userid'=>$userid,
    'isowner'=>false
   );

  }
```

Resulting output :

```
ArrayArray ( )
```

why `count($gibs)` not returning any thing.

thats why the flow don't going in if condition.

Comment: `count()` *returns* a value. In your case `count($gibs);` does nothing.

Comment: what is count($gibs) exactly returning? please vardump or print_r it!

Comment: ... Maybe because `Db::getResult($sql,$query);` is returning an empty result set?

Comment: Is your SQL statement actually returning any rows?

Comment: var_dump(count($gibs));//returns int(0)
print_r(count($gibs));//returns 0

Comment: Db::getResult($sql,$query); returning array()

Comment: Then your SQL statement is returning no rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the output of `count($gibs);` you should assign the function to some variable, or print it:

```
print_r(count($gibs));
```

In your case, it's value will be `0`, because `$gibs` array is empty (it is seen out of the `print_r` output).

`If` condition might not work, because `$gibid == 0`